# iMac: Alert message “No space on the boot partition. Close one or more programs to continue.”

Tags: macos, imac

The problem is that there is only a single partition with a LOT of space on it. Reboot helps for several days. Then this alert pops up again (and no way to hide it).

If you ignore the alert, everything works fine.

Has anybody encountered this problem?

[image: Screen-shot attached]

Answer (score 0):

You're running out of space on your hard drive. It takes awhile for the alert to come back after a reboot because you have *some* space, just not *enough* space. (The free space is taken up by the memory that's been paged to disk my the virtual memory system.)

You need to delete some files to make sure you have at least 5-10 GB free space on your boot disk; OS X isn't really happy with less than that.

Comment: On my hard drive more than 100GB free. That's the problem. I don't understand what it needs.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky Can you post a screenshot of the alert message you get? (You can take a screenshot of a region on the screen by hitting Command-Shift-4 and then selecting a box to capture.)

Comment: Took more than week to get this message. But finally here it is. A screen-shot is attached.

Comment: It could be that some temp files are filling up the disk, but are not reported by Disk Utility. Try the following: open Terminal.app (in Utilities) and type `sudo du -h /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/ | tail -n1` and compare the resulting number with the value of the used disk space that Disk Utility reports (do that as `sudo` so that you don't see `permission denied` messages for system directories). It may take some time to run this commands, as it computes the disk usage for each folder on that disk.

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky Lupincho is right - run his command to see if Disk Utility has the right free space (it might not show temporary stuff, though I'd expect it to).